# Converting UTF8 Data to SQL_ASCII

Tags: 7, forms, database

I want to convert my query results from a database, which is `SQL_ASCII` database encoded, to `UTF-8`.

```
$result = $query->execute;
$converted_data = array();
foreach($result as $record){
    $converted_data[count($converted_data)] = drupal_convert_to_utf8($record->name, 'sql-ascii');
}
```

I used `drupal_convert_to_utf8` but it returns blank all the time. I was confused if `sql-ascii` should be the second parameter of drupal_convert_to_utf8. The database encoding, where the query results is fetched, is `SQL_ASCII` in `postgres`.

UPDATE:

According to the [official documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21unicode.inc/function/drupal_convert_to_utf8/7.x), It

> Requires the iconv, GNU recode or mbstring PHP extension.

What are they? Am I going to install/include it or what?

Comment: I do not think that you can change the encoding if SQL_ASCII is set in PostgreSQL (see [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/multibyte.html)). Taking a database backup, deleting the database, and re-creating as UTF-8 seems to be the suggested method at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090858/how-do-you-change-the-character-encoding-of-a-postgres-database and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380924/how-can-i-change-database-encoding-for-a-postgresql-database-using-sql-or-phppga

If the client encoding is SQL_ASCII, then maybe locale is funky in PHP/PDO?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/admin/reports/status` and take a look at your unicode library. If you don't have multibyte support, install it: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

I.e. for ubuntu like systems it's `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring` for PHP7.

EDIT:

You could try 'auto' instead of 'sql_ascii', and btw., you can skip the count() call and can just write `$converted_data[] = drupal_...`

END EDIT

Comment: I found "Unicode library PHP Mbstring Extension" in admin/reports. How will I know if I have to install it?

Comment: Go to /admin/reports/status/php and search for "Multibyte Support", should be "enabled" - then we need to search for other problems.

Comment: 'extension=php_mbstring.dll' in php.ini was already enabled. I tried finding php_mbstring.dll at php/ext folder in windows and it does exist. But my problem still occurs.